# How can 2 controllers communicate with 1 view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like one view to have access in 2 controllers. What I mean
I have **Controller A** and **Controller B**
and on the view i have 2 divs: **Div A** with content info from **Controller A** and **Div b** with content info from **Controller B**. Is it possible? Can someone give me a hint on how or show me a simple example?

Comment: Have you thought about making it a shared view?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's too early for me. Use partials to get data from two controllers on the same view at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look at partial views: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1831-how-to-create-partial-views-mvc-tutorial-number-10.aspx
Also you can place your view file into Shared folder and reference it by a name: `return View("commonView");`

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using partial views.

Create a different partial views to show content from 2ND controllers render it on first view that has already data from 1st controller.
you can render partial view using following razor syntax:

```
 @Html.Partial("name of partial view").
```